# How to modify olcSuffix OpenLDAP? ldap_modify: Other (e.g. implementation specific) error (80)

Tags: openldap

Woe is me! I have to deal with good ol' OpenLDAP.  I have installed OpenLDAP by installing RPMs `openldap-servers`, `openldap` and `openldap-clients`. I want to change the `olcSuffix` from the default:

```
olcSuffix: dc=my-domain,dc=com
```

To my real domain.  So I created this file, ex.ldif:

```
# pwd
/etc/openldap
# cat ex.ldif
dn: olcDatabase{2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com
```

Then I execute:

```
# ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ex.ldif
```

But I get this error message:

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g. implementation specific) error (80)
```

And nothing is updated in my /etc/openldap/slapd.d configs.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled selinux and the problem went away.